# Index(match()) or lookup to return first non null / empty value

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm using an index(match()) function to return a value based on the name of a column header. However, I've recently learned that a column header can appear 4 times in my data. However, there would only ever be one populated, the others would always be empty.

Whilst I could do a nested if `=(isblank(...)# do stuff)` I wondered if there was a more sophisticated way to tell GSheets to return the first non null / empty value, kind of like the SQL `coalesque()` function.

Is there?

Current formula looks like this:

```
=index('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$DY,match($A2,'Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$A,0),match(I$1,'Form Responses 1'!$A$1:$DY$1,0))
```

However, this piece is the problem piece:

```
match(I$1,'Form Responses 1'!$A$1:$DY$1,0)
```

This is because I$1 appears 4 times in range `Form Responses 1'!$A$1:$DY$1`. The one that I want is the one that does not return a empty cell when nested in `index()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a more simple case when all the data is on single sheet.

[image]

The formula is:

`=QUERY(TRANSPOSE({A1:E1;FILTER(A2:E8,A2:A8 = 2)}),
"select Col2 where Col2 is not null and Col1 = 'foo' limit 1")`

---

- number `2` is criteria by row (`$A2` in your sample)
- text `foo` is criteria by column ( replace it with `" & I$1 & "` )

**How it works**

- `{A1:E1; filter }` is to get headers and desired row in one array
- `TRANSPOSE` is to use query
- `where Col2 is not null` is to get rid of empty cells
- `limit 1` is like `select first 1`